# how to add a custom label and content in django admin form

Tags: python, django

Hi say i have a address fields in my module.py as follows,

```
class Employee(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name="Name")
       Add1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name="Line 1")
       Add2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name="Line 2")
       city = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name="City")
       Zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 100,verbose_name="ZIP CODE")
```

Now in admin form how can i display all under one category,as follows ,

```
ADDRESS:
LINE 1:
LINE 2:
CITY:
ZIP CODE:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets).

In admin.py:

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name',)
        }),
        ('Address', {
            'fields': ('Add1', 'Add2', 'city', 'zipcode',)
        }),
    )
```